# Convert hex string to ansistring in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, unicode, hex

I used to use this function to convert hex string to string in Delphi 6 :

```
const
testSign = '207F8060287F585054505357FFD55861';

function Hex2Dec(const data: string): byte;
var
  nH1, nH2: byte;
begin
  if data[1] in ['0' .. '9'] then
    nH1 := strtoint(data[1])
  else
    nH1 := 9 + ord(data[1]) - 64;
  if data[2] in ['0' .. '9'] then
    nH2 := strtoint(data[2])
  else
    nH2 := 9 + ord(data[2]) - 64;
  Result := nH1 * 16 + nH2;
end;

function HexStrToStr(const HexStr: string): string;
var
  BufStr: string;
  LenHex: Integer;
  x, y: Integer;
begin
  LenHex := Length(HexStr) div 2;
  x := 1;
  y := 0;
  while y <> LenHex do
  begin
    Inc(y);
    BufStr := BufStr + Chr(Hex2Dec(HexStr[x] + HexStr[x + 1]));
    Inc(x, 2);
  end;
  Result := BufStr;
end;
```

Now I want to use the function with Delphi 2010.

```
const
testSign: AnsiString = '207F8060287F585054505357FFD55861';

function Hex2Dec(const data: ansistring): byte;
var
  nH1, nH2: byte;
begin
  if data[1] in ['0' .. '9'] then
    nH1 := strtoint(data[1])
  else
    nH1 := 9 + ord(data[1]) - 64;
  if data[2] in ['0' .. '9'] then
    nH2 := strtoint(data[2])
  else
    nH2 := 9 + ord(data[2]) - 64;
  Result := nH1 * 16 + nH2;
end;

function HexStrToStr(const HexStr: ansistring): ansistring;
var
  BufStr: ansistring;
  LenHex: Integer;
  x, y: Integer;
begin
  LenHex := Length(HexStr) div 2;
  x := 1;
  y := 0;
  while y <> LenHex do
  begin
    Inc(y);
    BufStr := BufStr + Chr(Hex2Dec(HexStr[x] + HexStr[x + 1]));
    Inc(x, 2);
  end;
  Result := BufStr;
end;
```

Output from first code in D6 :

```
' '#$7F'€`('#$7F'XPTPSWÿÕXa'
```

Output from second code in D2010 :

```
' '#$7F#$0080'`('#$7F'XPTPSWÿÕXa'
```

How do I fix the code in D2010 so it can produces same result like D6?

Comment: i'm not qoing to participate in longest answer contest. know your library, use `Classes.BinToHex()` and `Classes.HexToBin()`

Comment: ... as I suggested in my answer below...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides the solutions others provided, you can also make use of the built-in function:

```
function HexStrToStr(const HexStr: string): string;
var
  tmp: AnsiString;
begin
  Assert(not Odd(Length(HexStr)), 'HexToStr input length must be an even number');
  SetLength(tmp, Length(HexStr) div 2);
  HexToBin(PWideChar(HexStr), @tmp[1], Length(tmp));
  result := tmp;
end;
```

This implementation assumes that the hex-encoded string has been an Ansistring in the first place. For flexibility I suggest to use *TBytes* instead.

Comment: @David, because the built-in doesn't handle uppercase A-F.

Comment: @Cosmin then just throw in a call to `UpperCase`!

Comment: @Cosmin, at least in Delphi XE it doesn't matter what you throw in. HexToBin handles lowercase letters as well as uppercase ones.

Comment: @David, UpperCasing a string to call a trivial 5 LOC function is not smart: you'll make a complete copy of the string in the process. In my answer I tried to keep string copying and reallocation to a minimum, because that's where the performance hit is going to be.

Comment: @cosmin if you were worried about performance you wouldn't choose this woeful representation of the data!

Comment: @Uwe, the implementation in Delphi 2010 can't handle uppercase A-F. Don't know about XE.

Comment: @David, as I mentioned in my answer I suspect (hope!) the string-as-hex-constant was just an example.

Comment: @Cosmin, I digged a bit and compared the D2010 implementation with the XE one: they are identical. Please try it.

Comment: @Uwe, I'm feeling rather stupid right now. First let me say `HexToBin` is perfectly capable of handling upper case hex chars in Delphi 2010. Then let me point the finger at Embarcadero's documentation: [Classes.HexToBin Function](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_HexToBin@PAnsiChar@@Integer.html), especially this Note after the description: `Note: The hexadecimal number must use lower-case characters; HexToBind does not recognize upper-case characters.`. **HexToBind** is not my typo.

Comment: @Cosmin, the [latest help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.HexToBin) reads the same way but you can draw Embarcadero's attention to this by leaving comments on the discussion tab for that page.